# Every-time i update the database the whole container is loading. How can I stop it to only a single container

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a form on right of container and some jobs on left of container. When ever the job is updated dynamically the form position is getting parallel to updated job.The thing is every-time i update the database the whole container is loading. How can I stop it to only a single container. The image is shown below:

[image]
**job.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <?php
        include('admin/config.php');
            $host    = "localhost";
            $user    = "root";
            $pass    = "";
            $db_name = "redeem_system";
            $lastId="";

            //create connection
            $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

            //test if connection failed
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM job_update";

            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)

            {
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

            {
        ?>


<div class="container-fluid" style="font-family: 'open sans'!important;">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" >
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php echo $row['id']?>" aria-expanded="true"  class="trigger collapsed">
                         <?php echo $row['job_name'];?>
                        </a>
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" >
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="iconlist iconlist-color nobottommargin" style="list-style-type: disc!important;">
                            <?php
                             echo '<li>'.nl2br($row['job_description']).'</li>'?>
                       </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php 
                }
            }
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <div id="job-apply" class="heading-block highlight-me">
                    <h2>Apply Now</h2>
                    <span>And we'll get back to you within 48 hours.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty sure I have seen that exact same screenshot a couple of days ago already, and that I asked for clarification of the rather unclear question in comments there. What happened to that, did you just delete it? What you are actually trying to ask is as unclear to me now as it was then. All I can say at a glance is that you are nesting bootstrap columns directly into columns here, which is not how the grid works, columns need to be children of a row.

Comment: @CBroe I have deleted that question as many people said it was not clear. Now the thing is I want "Apply Noe" text to come in same line to "Web Development" Job.

Comment: Your whole code makes very little sense, you start a new `container-fluid` element on each loop iteration, that is of course absolute nonsense. You want to output multiple records inside a single column by the looks of it, so the loop itself would of course belong _inside_ of the opening and closing element of that column.

Comment: @CBroe How can I change it. Can u please explain me

Comment: I would suggest that you first of all build this in static HTML; until it looks the way you want. Then you can figure out what the script logic to create this dynamically needs to be afterwards.

Comment: Statically it is working pretty fine...Then only I started to do it dynamically. The thing is every-time i update the database the whole container is loading. How can  I stop it to only a single container.

Comment: Well then you got to figure out the proper logic to re-create what you got statically now dynamically using the loop. Your static version likely does not have `<div class="container-fluid" ...>` in there multiple times, so you need to think a bit about what to place where - before, inside and after the loop - to get the same output structure. _“The thing is every-time i update the database the whole container is loading. How can I stop it to only a single container.”_ - that would be a whole different question altogether, then you’re looking at AJAX to only replace parts of the current page …

Comment: @CBroe Can u please help me with a solution.

Comment: No, because first of all this is too broad, and second of all the code you have shown so far does not even seem to have anything to do with actually _updating_ anything, this provides output only.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the help..